# Casting subclass from base class where subclass has generic in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, generics, subclass

I have a base class type and a subclass type, where the subclass includes a generic type. If I have the subclass stored in the form of the base class type but I would like to type cast it back to the subclass type, Swift won't seem to let me.

Below is an example of what I mean:

```
class Base {

}

class Next<T> : Base where T : UIView {
    var view: T
    init(view: T) {
        self.view = view
    }
}

let a: [Base] = [Next(view: UIImageView()), Next(view: UILabel())]
for item in a {
    if let _ = item as? Next {
        print("Hey!")
    }
}
```

Why is `"Hey!"` never printed?

---

**EDIT:**

`"Hey!"` is printed if the cast reads:

```
if let _ item as? Next<UIImageView> ...
```

but only for the case of the UIImageView class.

*and*

`"Hey!"` is printed if one of the items in the array `a` is:

```
Next(view: UIView())
```

Ideally, I would like to not know what type the generic is when casting, but I realise this may not be possible.

Comment: You want to print "Hey!" is it's a subclass of `UIView`?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I want it to print "Hey!" no matter what type the generic type is

Answer (score 4):

The generic `Next<T>` is a template of sorts that creates unique separate classes. `Next<UIView>` and `Next<UIImageView>` are two completely unrelated types.

You can unite them with a protocol:

```
class Base {

}

class Next<T> : Base where T : UIView {
    var view: T
    init(view: T) {
        self.view = view
    }
}

protocol NextProtocol { }

extension Next: NextProtocol { }

let a: [Base] = [Next(view: UIImageView()), Next(view: UILabel()), Base()]
for item in a {
    if item is NextProtocol {
        print("Hey!")
    } else {
        print("Only a Base")
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> Hey!
> Hey!
> Only a Base
> ```

By defining a protocol such as `NextProcotol` that all classes derived from `Next<T>` conform to, you can refer to them as a group and distinguish them from other classes that derive from `Base`.

**Note:** To check if an `item` is of a type, use `is` instead of checking if the conditional cast `as?` works.

Comment: How are they completely unrelated? Why is there not some relation using the `Next` class? (not disagreeing, genuinely asking)

Comment: The generic `Next<T>` is a template of sorts that creates unique separate classes.  By defining a protocol such as `NextProcotol` that all classes derived from `Next<T>` conform to, you can refer to them as a group.

Comment: didn't notice  you answered already, take my upvote sir. ill leave mine probably has info someone could use

Comment: @vacawama can you edit your answer add more details about whats going on and why. so i can also delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your example I was expecting it to fail during compilation.

It seems that as long as you specify a concrete base class for your T (in this case UIView), then the compiler can infer that class in `as` or `is` statements. So when you type `item as? Next` the compiler understands `item as?`Next` because UIView is a concrete type.

This would not work if instead of UIView you would use a protocol. Also, simply using `Next` instead of `Next<UIView>` (or `Next<concrete subclass of UIView>`) will result in a compiler error outside an `is` or `as` statement.

Answer (score 0):

This is where protocols comes to help.

you need a dummy protocol to confirm `Next` to it

And use that dummy protocol to check your items types.

Therefore we create a dummy protocol confirm `Next` to it  and use that protocol to compare `items`.

code would be something like this.

```
class Base {

}

class Next<T> : Base where T : UIView {
    var view: T
    init(view: T) {
        self.view = view
    }
}
protocol  MyType  {

}

extension Next: MyType {}

let a: [Base] = [Next(view: UILabel()), Next(view: UILabel())]
for item in a {
    if let _ = item as? MyType {
        print("Hey!")
    }
}
```

`UIView` is super class for all the `UIElements`.

saying this will result into true,

`if let _ = UILabel() as? UIView {print("yes") }`

`Next` does not confirm to `UIView` but rather it requires something that confirm to `UIView` therefore you can't use the subs of `UIView` to check if they are `Next`, next have no exact type,

here we use the dummy protocol above !